# QMap<QString, Class*> SIGSEGV при вставке значения

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

В проекте создается экземпляр класса `DatabaseManager`. В нем я создаю экземпляры класса `Database` в функции `setupNewDatabase`. Когда я пытаюсь добавить в `QMap<QString, Database*>` указатель и ключ, приложение выдает `SIGSEGV` и останавливает на вызове функции `detach()` в классе QMap. Выполняется все в одном потоке.
Код:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>
#include <QMapIterator>
#include "../core/database.h"

class DatabaseManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DatabaseManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);
             ~DatabaseManager();

    bool    setupNewDatabase(QString competition);

private:
    QMap<QString, Database*> m_Databases;
};
```

---

```
#include "databasemanager.h"

DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {

}

bool DatabaseManager::setupNewDatabase(QString competition) {
    Database *database = new Database();
    if (database->createDatabase(competition)) {
        m_Databases.insert(competition, database); << CRASH
        return true;
    } else {
        m_lastDatabaseError = database->lastError();
        database->deleteLater();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Компилятор MinGW, Qt 5.11.2

Comment: Так в `QMap<QString, Database*>` или в `QMap<QString, Competiton*>`? Интересно, а ошибка повторится: `m_Databases[competition] = database;`?

Comment: @gil9red, конечно `Database`, исправил. Тоже краш.

Comment: Попробуйте создать словарь в куче и повторить

Comment: попробуйте заменить эту строку на `m_Databases[competition] = database; `

Comment: @goldstar_labs аналогичный результат

Comment: @gil9red при создании в куче аналогично

Comment: Небольшой пример воспроизводящий проблему набросать сможете ? А то так это гадание на кофейной гуще - мы же не видим всех ваших исходников.

Comment: Я вот сделал небольшой пример с структурой `struct A{int x;};` и `QMap<QString, A*> m` и у меня ничего не падает при вызове `m.insert("1", new A());`. Да и не должно падать. Только память надо не забыть почистить (наподобие такого `while (!m.empty()){ delete m.take(m.firstKey()); }`)

Comment: попробуйте в main.cpp создать QMap<QString, int*> (куча/стек) и вставить в него элемент. проблема сегфолта в мапе связана с потерей ссылочной целостности содержимого. Если в main.cpp обычный мап отработает без ошибок, то значит кьют в порядке и уже надо искать, где и как используется ваш класс DatabaseManager  и почему мап переходит в невалидное состояние. Дополнительно покажите код, где и как вы создаете и используете объект класса DatabaseManager.

Comment: краш при первой вставке, или до этого были вставки/удаления?

Comment: Если ваш мап не пустой в момент вызова инсерт и содержит битые указатели (или битые ссылки на строки), то проблема в этом

Comment: я к этому и спросил про не первую вставку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не был инициализирован класс `DatabaseManager`(да, очень тупая ошибка)